# Launch WhatsApp web from URL

Tags: google-chrome, whatsapp, web-whatsapp

I mean to put together an URL that leads me to a composing message in a WhatsApp web tab in Chrome.

The [official](https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/chats/how-to-use-click-to-chat) click-to-chat method is with
https://wa.me/ .

That produces the following pop up (number removed)

[image]

with the URL https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=targetnumber&text=&source=&data=&app_absent=

Clicking on *Open URL:whatsapp* only closes the popup.
Clicking on *CONTINUE TO CHAT* brings the popup again.

I mean to use Web Whatsapp, not the desktop application.

I tried two alternatives that *might* work

```
whatsapp://send?phone=<number>
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=<number>
```

Both produce the same result as above.

**How can I solve this?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are testing from browser you just replace api.whatsapp.com with web.whatsapp.com and it'll redirect you to the final send/compose window (which actually shows if you click cancel twice saying the app is not installed on the api.whatsapp.com link) whatsapp page adds a link

[image]

Comment: This works. 
It is strange that the official documentation tells `wa.me` works with WhatsApp web, and it does not mention requiring the desktop app.

Comment: yeah that was before the wa.me url shortener days and kept working for me

Comment: Actually, changing "api" to "web" in the direct URL for starting a chat, open up directly in WhatsApp Web, without even asking to download the desktop app or where to open this link. Which is even better... Great answer, thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

I want to give a small contribution about this behavior of the WhatsApp click-to-chat.

After having the same trouble today (march 22, 2024), [Bashar Al-Abdulhadi's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1570649/653259) helped me, but only after I checked the box "always accept opening apps from this site", or something like that, on the pop up that shows.

So, check that box, cancel the pop up, click the "Continue to Chat" button again and the "use WhatsApp Web" button will show up. Also, I noticed that the click-to-chat works on Firefox out-of-the-box, no workarounds required.